# Advanced Installer - search for file in global assembly cache (gac)

Tags: file, search, find, advanced-installer, global-assembly-cache

I have an Advanced Installer setup and during the installation process I need to find out whether Crystal Reports is installed on a system or not. It seems the best way is to look for the existence of CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll in the global assembly cache. More info here: https://answers.sap.com/questions/9165705/determine-if-cr-runtime-is-installed.html

I tried the search function of Advanced Installer, but it expects a full path of the file. What I want to do is to search for the assembly in the GAC directory (C:\windows\assembly) and sub directories.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is to search the registry.

Answer (score 1):

This should be easy with Advanced Installer. Add a new file search, right click on the search item and use [Add Search Location] - [Folder] option. Have a look at this configuration:

[image]

Comment: I tried this a couple of times and it didn't work as expected. Switched to registry search now and it works fine. Thanks.